# Select customers and current month revenue, where there is Zero revenue for the last 6 months

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have to find customer list,with current month revenue,where there is zero revenue for the last 6 months.

```
    DECLARE @cm AS DATE = (
            SELECT cm
            FROM dbo.datebreak
            )

    SELECT cmt_ACCOUNTS.[GA CUSTOMER ID]
        ,SUM(REVENUE) AS REV
    FROM cmt_ACCOUNTS
    INNER JOIN MDATA ON cmt_ACCOUNTS.[ACCOUNT NUMBER] = MDATA.[AccNumber]
    WHERE (MDATA.TobyBill = @cm)
    GROUP BY cmt_ACCOUNTS.[GA CUSTOMER ID]
        ,cmt_ACCOUNTS.[CUSTOMER NAME]
        ,MDATA.TERR
        ,MDATA.CHANNEL
        ,MDATA.ASM
        ,MDATA.EMPNAME
        ,MDATA.[Group Product]
        ,MDATA.TobyBill
    HAVING (MDATA.[Group Product] = N'TDI')
        AND MDATA.CHANNEL = 'TSR'
        AND (
            MDATA.TobyBill BETWEEN DATEADD(month, - 6, @cm)
                AND DATEADD(month, - 1, @cm)
            AND sum(REVENUE) <= 0
            )
```

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Why didn't it work?

Comment: not sure. this is not returning any values. i tried my best!

Comment: Can you provide some **consumable** sample data please, along with your expected results?

Comment: sum(revenue) is probably returning null, presuming that you don't have a bunch of $0 entries in the database.   Try  and isnull(sum(revenue)),0) <= 0   But even with that, I'm not sure I follow your having statement -- it seems wrong to me.